# When do I have to use TensorFlow's FileWriter.flush() method?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am currently working at a slightly bigger TensorFlow project and tried to visualize certain variables of my network as usual, i.e. doing this workflow

1. declare what variables i want to track via `tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)`
2. collect them via `summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()`
3. declare my writer as `writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('PATH')` and adding the graph
4. evaluate the summary operation during my training iterations via `s = sess.run(summary_op)`
5. and finally adding it to my writer via `writer.add_summary(s, epoch)`

Usually this does the job for me. But this time, I only got the graph showing up and when I inspected the event-file, I found it to be empty. By coincidence, I found somebody suggesting to use `writer.flush()` after adding my summary as a 6th step. This resolved my problem.

As a consequence, the logical follow-up question is: **when and how do I have to use `FileWriter.flush()` to make tensorflow work correctly?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can call `flush` whenever you want, really. This is probably clear for you, but just in case (and for other readers), `FileWriter` does not immediately write the given summaries to disk. This is because writing to disk is relatively slow, and if you are creating very frequent summaries (i.e. each batch) doing so could damage your performance, so `FileWriter` keeps a buffer of events that get written only "every once in a while" (and finally when it is closed). However, this means that TensorBoard will not see the written summaries immediately. `flush` is there to force the `FileWriter` to write to disk whatever it has in memory.

If you are producing summaries with low frequency (e.g. every 100 batches), it is probably fine to just call `flush` after `add_summary`. If you produce summaries constantly, but are not satisfied with the syncing frequency of `FileWriter`, you can have a `flush` for example every once in ten times, or something like that. I mean, you can also have it on every single iteration, and it may not make such a big difference, but it will not give you such a big benefit either. Of course, any potential performance impact will depend on your problem and your infrastructure (it is not the same logging scalars than images, or logging to a local SSD drive than to network storage, or having big, slow batches of hundreds of elements than tiny, fast batches of just a few).

In general, though, it is rarely a significant performance factor. For simple scenarios, the suggestion you got of adding `flush` after `add_summary` (one `flush`, if you have several calls to `add_summary` do not `flush` after each of them, only after the last one) is most likely good enough.

EDIT: [`tf.summary.FileWriter`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter) actually offers a construction parameter, `flush_secs`, that defines how frequently the writer will automatically flush pending events to disk. By default it is two minutes. There is also a `max_queue`, which defines the size of the internal events queue (the buffer of events).

Comment: That makes perfectly sense now. I wasn't aware of the fact that FileWriter buffers summaries. Thank you!

Comment: for `max_queue`, if the current size is 10 of the default value, when a new event comes, will the writer flush?

Comment: Since there is `flush_secs`, should I call `.flush()`? I mean does the `tf.summary.FileWriter` automatically call `.flush()` in `.add_summary()`?

Comment: @GoingMyWay It is not very documented but, as I understand it, `max_queue` and `flush_secs` determine when the file writer will flush. If you have `max_queue` events buffered and submit one more, the file write will flush, and if it has been more than `flush_secs` since the last flush it will also flush (I don't know if this is done by a dedicated thread or only after an event is submitted). So, `add_summary` will not always flush. However, the writer will always flush on closing.

Comment: Thank you, I found it will flush after the flush_secs https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/bab74a15d9ad6bb9066b3e31d601d6a45b1cb221/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/event_file_writer.py#L170